# Need example of use of PreparedStatement with Anorm scala

Tags: mysql, scala, playframework-2.1, anorm

I am using Anorm for querying a MySQL database from Playframework 2.1. I created a prepared statement like this.

```
import play.api.db.DB
import anorm._

val stat = DB.withConnection(implicit c => SQL("SELECT name, email FROM user WHERE id=?").filledStatement)
```

Now how do I use it? Am I event doing this right? I am totally ignorant of the anorm API and I already went through the source code without gaining much insight.

Code examples are more that welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good example on the Anorm usage is given in the respective [tutorial](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaAnorm). It also contains some examples that pass dynamic parameters to the queries. You should start by writing your query and replace declare placeholders like `{somePlaceholder}` in the query string. You can later assign values using the `.on()` method like this:

```
SQL(
  """
    select * from Country c 
    join CountryLanguage l on l.CountryCode = c.Code 
    where c.code = {countryCode};
  """
).on("countryCode" -> "FRA")
```

Or in your case:

```
import play.api.db.DB
import anorm._

val stat = DB.withConnection(implicit c =>
  SQL("SELECT name, email FROM user WHERE id={id}").on("id" -> 42)
)
```

Comment: So it is not necessary to get a java.sql.PreparedStatement from the filledStatement function? Fantastic. I was already doing that on my app. Cheers